# how to find a specific word in list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have to find whether a word is in list, if it is found in the list then then a file will write that list with tag "1" else file will write the list with tag "0". My python code is below which encountered an error of    **TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list**

```
f2 = open("C:/Python26/Semantics.txt",'w')
sem = ["cells", "gene","factor","alpha", "receptor", "t","promotor"];
with open("C:/Python26/trigram.txt") as f:
contents = f.readlines()
for lines in contents:
    tokens = lines.split('$')
    for t in tokens:
        if t.strip() in sem:
            f2.write(tokens+"\t"+"1 \n");
        else:
            f2.write(tokens+"\t"+"0 \n");
f2.close()
```

**my file looks like this:**

```
IL-2$gene$expression$and
IL-2$gene$expression$and$NF-kappa
IL-2$gene$expression$and$NF-kappa$B
IL-2$gene$expression$and$NF-kappa$B$activation
gene$expression$and$NF-kappa$B$activation$through
expression$and$NF-kappa$B$activation$through$CD28
```

**My desired output**

```
IL-2 gene expression and    1
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa   1
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B   1
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B activation   1
gene expression and NF-kappa B activation through   1
expression and NF-kappa B activation through CD28   0
```

**in case i want to generate the output like**

```
Token                                            cells   gene    factor……. promoter   
IL-2 gene expression and                          0       1       0     ………       0 
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa                 0       1       0     ………       0
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B               0       1       0     ………       0
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B activation    0       1       0     ………       0
gene expression and NF-kappa B activation through 0       1       0     ………       0  
expression and NF-kappa B activation through CD28 0       0       0     ………       0
```

i think there will required a little bit change in code

Comment: why you end sem with semicolon, no need to semicolon in python

Comment: After you paste in code, select the whole block and and press Ctrl+K to indent **all of it**. Your program want run as displayed because it has indentation errors. Andy why is there a semicolon after several lines without a statement following them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
sem = ["cells", "gene","factor","alpha", "receptor", "t","promotor"]
with open("C:/Python26/trigram.txt") as f, open("C:/Python26/Semantics.txt",'w') as f2:
    for x in f:
        x = x.strip().split("$")
        print " ".join(x), len(set(sem) & set(x))
        f2.write("{} {}\n".format(" ".join(x), len(set(sem) & set(x))))
```

OR write to file instead of printing it to console

```
f2.write("{} {}\n".format(" ".join(x), len(set(sem) & set(x))))
```

Output:

```
IL-2 gene expression and 1
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa 1
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B 1
IL-2 gene expression and NF-kappa B activation 1
gene expression and NF-kappa B activation through 1
expression and NF-kappa B activation through CD28 0
```

> Explanation of `" ".join(x), len(set(sem) & set(x))`

" ".join(x): this will join the list delimited by white space

len(set(sem) & set(x)) :  set will give you list with no duplicate element, set(sem) & set(x) is same as `math` set and operation, will give you only match element from the two list, then i have takne length of the list

Comment: a mistake of x = x.strip.split("$") instead of x = x.strip().split("$"). thx for help :)

Comment: can u explain the line    print " ".join(x), len(set(sem) & set(x))

Comment: ValueError: zero length field name in format         error  in case of write in file

Comment: I case of writing in file code created an error on f2.write("{} {}\n".format(" ".join(x), len(set(sem) & set(x)))) and error is ValueError: zero length field name in format error

Comment: have you tried my latest edit?, can you show me full traceback??,

Comment: still error on line f2.write("{} {}\n".format(" ".join(x), len(set(sem) & set(x))))  of ValueError: zero length field name in format. I dont know why this occur, i m using python version 2.6

Comment: I fully copied ur code but the above mentioned error on above mentioned line is still there

Comment: may be try this then `f2.write(" ".join(x) + " " + str(len(set(sem) & set(x)))+"\n")`

Comment: I edit my question kindly check that and help me in writing the output like that way. For this purpose I used nested loop but that is not working